# NSFetchedResultsController and childController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In the [RootViewController](https://github.com/LeonB/Munin/blob/master/Classes/MuninMastersViewController.m) I do a fetch request to the core data store (?) and it returns an NSSet of, let's say, recipes. When a user selects a recipe in the rootviewcontroller I do a pushViewController and push one of the recipes to the childcontroller.

In the childController the user has the possibility to refresh the "recipe" so he can update the ingredients for example. When the users selects "refresh" I connect to the interwebs to receive new data. This new data I puth in self.recipe.ingredients.

This all works great. But then I want to reload the chilController view. All the refreshing stuff is done in the background so I want to emit a signal when the core data stuff is finished.

Hello NSFetchedResultsController! But to use NSFetchedResultsController you need a NSFetchRequest. And that NSFetchRequest is instantiated in my rootViewController.

So when I create a controllerDidChangeContent method in my rootViewController I see it getting triggered. But now is the question: how can I update my childViewController's tableview?

I thought about calling this method in my rootViewControllers' controllerDidChangeContent method:
[self.childController controllerDidChangeContent:controller]
So just passing on the fired method

Or when instantiating the childController, I could also pass on the fetchRequest to the childController and instantiating a new NSFetchedResultsController in the childController instance.

What would be the best of those two? Or are there other posibilities I haven't thinked of?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in one of my projects a slightly different way. I have the child controller create and use its own NSFetchRequest. It works well, but I'd be curious to hear if anybody recommends a different approach.

So using the terms of you app, here it goes: In the childController I created a brand new NSFetchRequest using the Ingredient entity, and put a predicate on it to find all Ingredients from my Recipe. Note: this assumes that you have an inverse relationship from Ingredient back to Recipe.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ingredient" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipe == %@", self.recipe];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

So childController uses this fetchRequest instead of the NSFetchRequest found in RootViewController. Whenever an Ingredient is added, deleted, or updated, the childController will now get the message. Just don't forget that childController will need to implement the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol.

Comment: Thanks dnorcott. I'll go with instantiating a new nsfetchrequest & nsfetchedresultscontroler object in the childController.